# iOS How to auto layout a view 3 x screen width?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I tried to place a `UIView` which is 3x the screen width (or 3x `UIScrollView`'s width) in `UIScrollView`.

`UIScrollView`'s width equal to the screen width.

How do I do this in AutoLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in code via pure AutoLayout, here's how you'd do it:

```
- (void)layoutUserInterface {
    // Placing the scrollView using AutoLayout
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    // Note: The "H:" is optional, but I like to be clear
    [self.view addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint
      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollview]|"
      options:0
      metrics:nil
      views:@{@"scrollview": self.scrollView}]];
    [self.view  addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint
      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollview]|"
      options:0
      metrics:nil
      views:@{@"scrollview": self.scrollView}]];

    // Placing the "wideView" using AutoLayout
    [self.scrollView addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint
      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[wideView]"
      options:0
      metrics:nil
      views:@{@"wideView": self.wideView}]];
    [self.scrollView addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint
      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[wideView]"
      options:0
      metrics:nil
      views:@{@"wideView": self.wideView}]];
    // Setting up the 3x width constraint
    [self.scrollView addConstraint:
     [NSLayoutConstraint
      constraintWithItem:self.wideView
      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
      toItem:self.view
      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
      multiplier:3.0f
      constant:0.0f]];
    // Figure out your "wideView's" height requirements

}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! I did all this xib layout programmatically by turn off the auto layout in xib. It is really kind of you to show the detail code. Thank you so much! I did not try it, just ask one more question, is there a way to autolayout a subview 3xwidth scrollview without using code?

Comment: I did not try it, but it looks like a right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a value for your views's width constraint and make an IBOutlet for this in your header file.

In your m file's viewDidLoad method get the width of the current device's screen, multiply by 3 and assign to your constraint's constant. And finally call your view's layoutIfNeeded method.

Is this clear enough or do you want me to make it more clear?

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! I did do it programmatically. and turn off the auto layout in xib...